# How to fix 'Failure loading test' in TeamCity Flutter build

Tags: flutter, dart, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to build a CICD instance of TeamCity for a Flutter project. Currently I have the command scripts to clone the Flutter repository and run `Flutter doctor`. However, my last step is not working -- running `Flutter test`.

Prior to the infinite loading attempt of the default `widget_test.dart`, a stacktrace comes out:

```
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #0      _WebSocketImpl.connect.<anonymous closure>.error (dart:_http/websocket_impl.dart:1049:9)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #1      _WebSocketImpl.connect.<anonymous closure> (dart:_http/websocket_impl.dart:1058:14)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #3      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #4      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #5      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #6      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #7      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #8      Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:400:22)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #11     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #12     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #13     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #14     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:483:5)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #15     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:513:7)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #18     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #19     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #20     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
[19:05:51]  [Step 2/2] Shell: #21     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
```

The final error is

```
Failed to load "/root/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/700f5361a835c53d/test/widget_test.dart":
[19:10:50]  [Step 2/2]   Test never connected to test harness.
[19:10:50]  [Step 2/2]   Test: /root/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/700f5361a835c53d/test/widget_test.dart
[19:10:50]  [Step 2/2]   Shell: /root/TeamCity/buildAgent/work/700f5361a835c53d/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/linux-x64/flutter_tester
```

Anyone run into a fix for this: Flutter is still pretty new and there aren't many documents on how to set this up.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

This is for a new TeamCity build. I've added the environment variable below as the proxy bit of flutter doctor was complaining:

`env.NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My teams default agent was overriding the variable env variable `no_proxy`
Within the command script I simply appended the `127.0.0.1` to the existing env variable and it worked.